# Programming Arduino via ICSP

Tags: programming, icsp

I'm trying to programming Arduino Nano with another Arduino Nano via ICSP. I have a 6-pin cable directly connected to the ICSP's pin of the second board:

```
ICSP NANO ISP 1
pin1 pin2 pin3
pin4 pin5 pin6


ICSP NANO 2 (to be programmed)
pin1 pin2 pin3
pin4 pin5 pin6
```

I have correspondingly wired pin 1 (ICSP) of nano1 to pin 1 (ICSP) Nano 2, pin 2 (ICSP) of nano 1 to pin 2 (ICSP) Nano 2, etc.

I make this step before flashing: getting the Arduino ISP with example sketch ArduinoISP, plug off the Arduino ISP and attach the 6-pin cable to the ICSP port of the second board, plug Arduino ISP to the USB port, in the *Tools* menu select *Arduino as ISP*, load with external programmer, and fail...

This is the log:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Sep 12 2016 at 17:24:16
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM12
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Errore durante il caricamento dello sketch
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: Get yourself a cheap $2 USBASP off eBay. Save yourself the hassle.

Comment: You shouldn't connect the two reset pins of both nanos. Connect the reset of the target to pin 10 of the programmer. Also, you need to prevent the programming nano from being reset when the serial connection is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try and read the [Arduino page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) about ArduinoISP.

Particularly, you will notice that pins 11, 12, 13 and Vcc and GND are all common, BUT the reset pin is not common to both boards. So I suggest you to detach the pin 5 of ICSP from the ArduinoISP board and connect it to its pin 10. Or, if you prefer, connect

```
ISP - Target
+5V - +5V
GND - GND
11  - 11
12  - 12
13  - 13
10  - RST
```

Then try again

Comment: thanks, now im getting that `avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x14

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x02

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
         Hardware Version: 4728160
         Firmware Version: 0.4598883
         Topcard         : STK502
         Vtarget         : 1.8 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: stk500_initialize(): (b) protocol error, expect=0x10, resp=0x01`

Comment: Did you try to flash the ArduinoISP again, then connect the "slave" nano (remember, the pin RST on the slave should be connected to pin 10 on the master) without connecting the slave to the USB and then try to flash with external? If so, try to flash the bootloader (there should be a command in the menus like "flash bootloader", but I don't remember where

Comment: i miss the PIN 10 to connect to the RST pin , thanks again

Comment: @FrancescoValla Glad this fixed the issue